# How to return page number of various headings in ms word

Tags: ms-word

I have a custom contents page for a large document and cannot use the automatic contents features due to strict formatting requirements. Is there a way to populate the manual contents with page numbers for each heading in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the bookmarks feature in MS Word 2013 and later.
2. Select the heading you want to reference and name it something sensible using the bookmark tool.
3. Insert a document field called 'pageRef' into the part of the contents page where you want to add the page number, and point it to the heading you named in 2.
4. Your contents will now auto-populate with the page numbers of each heading, and you don't have to use the nasty standard format.